# Get enum from specific number

Tags: c#, enums

I have `enum` like this :

```
   enum Numbers
    {
        SmallerThenThree = 3,
        SmallerThenFive = 5,
        SmallerThenTen = 10,
    }
```

Is it possible get item of `enum` by specific number? For example :

```
 var numberFour = 4;
        var enumOfNumber = (Numbers)numberFour; // There should be SmallerThenFive enum type
        var numberSix = 6;
        enumOfNumber = (Numbers)numberSix; // There should be SmallerThenTen enum type
```

Comment: If you had 10 and were looking for the exact match `SmallerThanTen`, then yes. This question, however, doesn't seem to be an appropriate use of enums, IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Reflection:

```
var number = 4;
var enumValue = (Numbers)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Numbers))
    .Cast<int>()
    .OrderBy(v => v)
    .FirstOrDefault(v => number < v);   

// Note: enumValue will be (Numbers)0 if the value is >= 10
```

Comment: Would you consider using `.DefaultIfEmpty(-1)` to show a 'not found' result?

Comment: special case treatment wasn't part of the question

Answer (score 0):

```
   var value= 4;
 Numbers enumDisplayStatus = (Numbers)value;
    string stringValue = enumDisplayStatus.ToString();
```

Comment: Re-read OP's question. If they input 4, they want `SmallerThanFive` to be the result. Yours won't do that.

Comment: It returns - "4"